# HEX 00 value between characters

Tags: hex

I have a file here that contais some texts, and I want edit them.
But between the characters have a decimal value 00. If I remove it, gives erros in the file and nothing appears in the program! But if I edit keeping the 00 values ​​between the letters, it works.
Have a program that "hide" these values? By this mode, it is very difficult for me to edit so many letters one by one in a file of 13 MB! Here goes a print:

http://img211.imageshack.us/img211/2286/fsfsz.png

What can I do?
Thanks all in advance!

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve. More information/context on what you're trying to do would be helpful.

Comment: I want edit the texts. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your file looks like an `UTF-16` text file, it means each character is coded in 16 bits instead of 8 bits.
If you try to edit this file as a standard text file, you get `null` characters between each letters.

You can use `libiconv` to convert the file format, or you can write your own converter.

Using `iconv` :

```
iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 yourFile.txt > fileToEdit.txt

iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-16 editedFile.txt > programFile.txt
```

If you're on Windows, you can use the [MinGW distribution of `libiconv`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/Base/libiconv/).

Comment: I will try here, but you want the file? I can upload to 4shared. Do you want the file? Thank you.

Comment: I did not manage. Here goes the file: http://www.mediafire.com/?a9xxv4l68jp6dlh
Please take a look. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The file is encoded in Unicode. UTF-16, most likely. If you open it in a decent text editor (e.g. Notepad++) it will automatically detect this and allow you to change the encoding. However, 'the program' (whatever that is) probably wants to consume the file with UTF-16 encoding. It's not clear why you're trying to change it but the answer is probably keep the 00s.

Comment: Ok thank you. I have the Notepad++ here, but he gives several NUL characters.